# Has array.includes negative impact on performance compared to multiple if statements?

Tags: javascript

I have gotten into the habit of using Array.includes as a replacement for longer if statements.

e.g.

```
let varibale = 'a';
if ['b', 'c', 'd'].includes(variable) ...
```

instead of

```
let varibale = 'a';
if variable === 'b' || variable === 'c' || variable === 'd' ...
```

I wonder if this has a notable negative impact on performance or any other technical drawbacks?

Comment: It might, depending on how the engine compiles it. But performance almost never matters - better to write DRY, readable code. Only work on performance once you've run a performance test and have identified some section(s) which are *actually* causing issues - until then, better to avoid premature optimization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array.includes` will always be slower but not by much.

That is because, you have some variable and using them you will create a dynamic variable which is an array. Then internally it'll loop and do lookup to test.

However, the GAIN is miniscule and will hardly matter:

Following is the [JSPerf link](https://jsperf.com/if-chain-vs-includes).

---

So what to use, my suggestion is to use `Array.includes`. Yes, it slower but its maintainable and easy to read. Most of the bundler like webpack or gulp, do internal optimizations but what is important is the readability. If a developer has to invest a min to understand the code, its waste of time you'll hardly gain in performance. Plus humans would be the one to interact most with code, so my suggestion is to have readaility.

Comment: **Note:** If you feel something is missing or can be added to make answer, better, Please feel free to edit and add your suggestion at bottom

Comment: not a correction, just a thought: I'd personally love the ECMA committee to add some sort of syntax like if(variable in [value1, value2, value3]), which would be changed behind the scenes into chained or checks

Comment: @CHowell Like an AND operations? Interesting idea for its usecase would limit to validation. I think you can use `.every` or `.some` based on implementation

Comment: Hm, if I run this test, `.includes()` comes out on top, though? https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/15414/0/chain-of-or-equals-vs-includes EDIT: okay, only in Safari and Chrome, in Firefox, it is WAY slower